# Memory mapped files optional write possible?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, memory-mapped-files, copy-on-write

When using memory-mapped files it seems it is either read-only, or write-only.  By this I mean you can't:

- have one open for writing, and later decide not to save it
- have open open for reading, and later decide to save it

Our application uses a writable memory-mapped file to save data files, but since the user might want to exit without saving changes, we have to use a temporary file which the user actually edits.  When the user opts to save the changes, the original file is overwritten with the temporary file so it has the latest changes.  This is cumbersome because the files can be very large (>1GB) and it takes a long time to copy them.

I've tried many combinations of the flags used to create the file mapping but none seem to allow the flexibility of saving on demand.  Can anyone confirm this is the case?  Our application is written in Delphi, but it uses the standard Windows API to create the mapping, in our case

```pas
FMapHandle := CreateFileMapping(FFileHandle, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 2 * 65536, nil);
FBasePointer := MapViewOfFile(FileMapHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, FileOffsetHigh,
FileOffsetLow, NumBytes);
```

Comment: There's nothing special about *memory-mapped* files here. If you write to a file — any file — then you've really written to it. Saving a file *is* writing to it. If you don't want to save, then don't write.

Comment: That's not totally true - you can write to a memory-mapped file without the changes being reflected in the underlying file, depending on the flags it was created with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can. By that I mean you *may* be able to, but it doesn't make any sense to me :-)

The whole point of a memory-mapped file is that it's a window onto the actual file. If you don't wany changes reflected in the file, you'll probably have to do something like batch up the changes in a data structure (e.g., an array of base address, size and data) and apply them when saving.

In which case, you wouldn't actually *need* the memory mapped file, just read in and maintain the chunks you want to change (lock the file first if there's a chance of multi-user access).

*Update:*

Have you thought of the possibility of, when doing a save, deleting the original file and just renaming the temporary file to the original file name? That's likely to be much faster than copying 1G of data from temporary to original. That way, if you don't want it saved, just delete the temporary file and keep the original.

You'll still have to copy the original data to the temporary file when loading but you won't have to copy the temporary data back (whether you save it or not) - that would halve the time taken.

Comment: I was afraid of that!  I thought perhaps that omitting FlushViewOfFile would cause the changes to be rejected.  Alas, no, it gets written anyway.

Comment: Hi yep, PaxDiablo, that's exactly what we do.  I should have mentioned that in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

Possible, but non-trivial.

You have to understand memory mapped basics, and the difference between the three modes of memory-mapped files. Both set aside a part of your virtual address space and create a mapping entry in an internal table. No physical RAM is initially allocated. Hence, when you DO try to access the memory, the CPU faults and the OS has to fix up. It does so by copying the file contents to RAM and mapping the RAM to your process, at the faulting address.

Now, the difference between the three modes is how the descriptors are set on the mapped pages. In all cases you get read access on the pages. (The first mode). However, if you ask for write access and subsequently write to it, on your first write the page is marked as writeable and dirty. It can then be written back to the original file, at the discretion of the OS (Second mode). Finally, it's possible to get copy-on-write semantics. You still start out with only read access to the page in memory. When you write to it, the CPU still faults and the OS needs to fix it up. With copy-on-write, that fixup is done by setting the backing store of the changed page to the page file, instead of the original mapped file.

So, in your case you want to use copy-on-write mode. If the user decides to discard the modifications, no problem. You simply discard the memory mapping. All pages that were modified in memory, and were backed by the page file are also discarded.

If the user does decide to save, you've got a slightly harder task. You now need to figure out which parts of the file have changed. Those changes are in memory, and you need to reapply those to the source file. You can do this with [Page Guards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366549.aspx). So, when the user decides to save, copy all modified pages to a separate memory block, remap the (unchanged) file for write, and apply the changes.

Comment: Thank-you, I will investigate it although the obvious complexity of it might overcome the benefits of it!

Comment: I wouldn't call it "obviously complex" actually. Really, the pageguard idea is just to create a list of modified page pointers. "Copying all modified pages" and "Applying the changes" both are trivial operations: `for each (srcPage in set) { CopyMemory(newPage.base, srcPage.base, Page::size); }`